# Shell script for removing tab from double quotes

Tags: database, shell

can anybody help me to remove tab from double quotes using shell script in text file.

Data in text file look like below

```
sgsgsgs hhjhjhhj    hjhhjh  hjhjjhj jhhjhj  "dhsdhsjhs  jjkkjkjj    kjkkjj"
```

highly Appreciated if anybody can help.

Regards

Adil

Answer (score 2):

Try this `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'"' -vOFS='"' '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub("\t", "", $i)} 1' file
```

It will remove the tab character between every pair of quotes on each line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the quotes only occuring two times on a line this might work for you:

```
sed 's_^\([^"]\+"[^\t]*\)\t\([^\t]*"\)$_\1\2_g' INPUTFILE
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for update this command is not working fine giving this error please if u can check   sed: -e expression #1, char 42: Invalid preceding regular expression

Comment: Answer updated. I'd recommend (if you want to use the Stackexchange sites in the future) to read the FAQ (e.g.: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote )